# React Hooks with Conditions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have written one component which is using the react hooks and it looks like

```
  export default props => {
  const [educations, setEducations] = useState([]);
  const [isAdd, setAdd] = useState(false);
  const [currentedcuation, setCurrentEducation] = useState(defaultEducation);
  const [currentid, setCurrentId] = useState("-1");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof props.currentProfileInfo !== "undefined") {
      if (props.currentProfileInfo) {
        if (educations.length === 0) {
          setEducations([...props.currentProfileInfo.education]);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return (
 <>
  {educations.map(item => {
      return (
        <EducationElement
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          type={props.type}
          education={item}
          currentedcuation={currentedcuation}
          isAdd={item.id === "-1" || item.id === currentid ? isAdd : false}
          onSave={onSave}
          onEdit={onEdit}
          dataChanged={dataChanged}
        />
      );
    })}
  </>
  );
}
```

basically what it will do it will render the child component based on the array so my questions is when my component loaded at that time I need to check condition like

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof props.currentProfileInfo !== "undefined") {
      if (props.currentProfileInfo) {
        if (educations.length === 0) {
          setEducations([...props.currentProfileInfo.education]);
        }
      }
    }
```

so I just want to confirm is it good practice to checking this kind of condition in useEffect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reason and based on your code, it would be a good idea to execute the useEffect hook only when `props.currentProfileInfo` changes. You can improve on your code like

```
export default props => {
  const [educations, setEducations] = useState([]);
  const [isAdd, setAdd] = useState(false);
  const [currentedcuation, setCurrentEducation] = useState(defaultEducation);
  const [currentid, setCurrentId] = useState("-1");

  useEffect(() => {
      if (props.currentProfileInfo && educations.length === 0) {
          setEducations([...props.currentProfileInfo.education]);
      }
  }, [props.currentProfileInfo]);

  return (
   <>
    {educations.map(item => {
      return (
        <EducationElement
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          type={props.type}
          education={item}
          currentedcuation={currentedcuation}
          isAdd={item.id === "-1" || item.id === currentid ? isAdd : false}
          onSave={onSave}
          onEdit={onEdit}
          dataChanged={dataChanged}
        />
      );
    })}
  </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please see the documentation for handling hooks with conditions. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html